# Drupal installation and domain naming strategy?

Tags: drupal, dns

I have a my main site, called "mysite.com" (for arguments sake). On this site, you will find my blog and everything I do. But I am starting another site that I want to run on my domain. However:

- The other site must have it's down domain name: newsite.com
- If people go to mysite.com/newsite it must redirec to newsite.com
- If people go to newsite.com, it must show the content of what they would see if they had gone to mysite.com/newsite in the past

So basically, I want a "page" or actually a whole section ( mysite.com/newsite/* ) to appear as newsite.com in the browser.

Why?

- I want both sites to run off one drupal installation
- I want both sites to look basically the same

However, keep in mind that I don't want to use a multi-drupal solution. i.e. a module that allows for more than one copy of drupal to run off 1 installation.

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/domain allows you to configure various things based on the domain, for example accessible nodes.

You can probably do the redirect with a Rewrite Rule, outside of Drupal or write a simple module that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple to do.  Just install the second site using a regular multi-site installation.  (Google "drupal multi-site instructions").  Then install the Path redirect module and create the external redirect to the new domain. http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect